# Why does the form not work in the index in my ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't seem to get my code to work. When I enter in the name and the year of birth, the output ends up being blank. I can't seem to pin point the problem. The goal is to output the name entered and their age this year. If entry for name isn't alphabetic then is says something. If birth year isn't numeric it says something.

Below are my model, index, and controller.

Index view:

```
@using Responsive.Models;
@model ResponsiveModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Age Calculator</h1> 
    <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div> 
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Name">Name:</label> 
            <input asp-for="Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="BirthYear">Birth Year:</label> 
            <input asp-for="BirthYear" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Age this year:</label> 
            <label>@ViewBag.FV.</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Calculate</button> 
            <a asp-action="Index">Clear</a>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Responsive.Models
{
    public class ResponsiveModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry must be alphabetic")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Name must be alphabetic")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must be a date in ")]
        [Range(1900, 2050, ErrorMessage = "Entry must be numeric")]
        public int? BirthYear { get; set; }

        public string CalculateAge()
        {
            int currentYear = 2023;
            string? age = Convert.ToString(currentYear - BirthYear);
            string finalValue = Name + " is " + age + ".";
            return finalValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Responsive.Models;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = "Taylor";
        ViewBag.BirthYear = 2000;
        ViewBag.FV = "_";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(ResponsiveModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.FV = model.CalculateAge();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Entering name and birth year doesn't output anything. Clear button does not work. It appears that the form is not working properly in the index.

Comment: You're not actually using any values from the model in your form.
You can use the "@Html" helper to bind the fields to your model.
E.g. "@Html.InputFor" etc.

Comment: *"the output ends up being blank"* - You're getting a blank page?  An expected page but with a specific value is blank?  Something else?

Comment: I hate this kind of "validation" so much, it's almost always wrong. 1900 minimum birthday is just baaaarely enough to hold the oldest person alive's birthday, but not if you wanted to make an account for a deceased person (which you do all the time for the government). Names with no spaces or regional characters speaks of a small, closed mind (Anaïs is the most popular baby name in France, for example). Middle names, apostrophes, Asian names, nothing.

Comment: I can almost feel the ubiquitously broken email regex coming in the next iteration.

Comment: Hi @Taylor Layton, what do you mean for `Entering name and birth year doesn't output anything`? Do you mean the age does not display after form submit? It works fine in my project. Do you debug the code to check if the post action receive the model? If it does not contain any value, could you pls F12 in the browser and check the Elements panel if the tag helper generate the id and name in the html, or it just display `asp-for`?

Answer (score 0):

**First Problem:** Post method does not contain `View()`. So you must redirect it to another method which has view.

For example:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Blog> blogs = await _context.Blogs                
            .ToListAsync();

        return View(blogs);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]        
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(BlogCreateVM blogCreateVM)
    {           
        //some code

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

**Second Problem**: Your `Get` method doesn't send model so you can't catch that model in view. That's why in your html `asp-for="Name"` only works like string. Not like `Model.Property`. Send `Responsive.Models` to `view` from `controller`.